# xcode picker output into array

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I have table cell view with which each cell must represent the output of a picker selection by the user.

The table cell view has two labels and a button. The button is to call up the picker of course.(little right arrow)

The first label i need to return the number of the cell row?

The second label needs to return the picker selection of the user.

This is what i have in my picker implementation method file for the button upon picker selection by the user:

```
    -(IBAction)buttonPressed
    {
NSInteger suitRow = [doublePicker selectedRowInComponent:
                      kSuitComponent];
NSInteger numberRow = [doublePicker selectedRowInComponent:
                        kNumberComponent];
NSString *suit = [suitTypes objectAtIndex:suitRow];
NSString *number = [numberTypes objectAtIndex:numberRow];

    This is where i need to put suit and number into array?
    i also want to return the row number?
}
```

So i need to save those two values and return them to my other view?

Comment: How are you displaying the picker view in the first place? Can you show that code? What is the datasource for your table view?

Comment: why do you need the data source? all i need to do is save suit and number as a string into an array as an object in ANOTHER view. How do you do that? Thanks

Comment: Well, the datasource is presumably the array you want to update with the picker selection, isn't it?

Comment: thats what I've been saying all along. If you look at the above i have the 2 reels outputting to two strings, suit and number. how do i save them as an object into an array, and then read the results of that array in another view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably the object in your array is already created since you are editing an existing row. So you should pass this object to your picker view controller, and edit it in the action above. When you return to the table view you may need to call `reloadData`

It may be worth looking at editing your cells in the same view, using the picker as the editing view of the field(s) in your cell. This would keep everything on the same controller and simplify your code as you'd know which item you were editing.