# Transfer picker output to another views array

Tags: objective-c, xcode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [xcode picker output into array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7376424/xcode-picker-output-into-array)

I have 2 views.

One of them has a picker with a button beneath it.

Here is my button code:

```
    -(IBAction)buttonPressed
{
NSInteger suitRow = [doublePicker selectedRowInComponent:
                      kSuitComponent];
NSInteger numberRow = [doublePicker selectedRowInComponent:
                        kNumberComponent];
NSString *suit = [suitTypes objectAtIndex:suitRow];
NSString *number = [numberTypes objectAtIndex:numberRow];

NSString *message = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:
                     @"%@ of %@.",number, suit];
}
```

The other view has a table cell id like to display the picker output in.

Specifically, I need to insert the picker output(*message above) into an array at a specific index in my other view, namely the index correlating to the row number. Now I have the row number sorted already.

I even know what to do with the array once its populated.

Please can somebody knowledgable advise me as to how can I  transfer the picker output from the picker view into my other views array on pressing the button beneath the picker?

Assuming this is possible in the first place right?

Comment: Trev, if my previous answer to your identical question wasnt right, why accept it? Who does that help? If you want to bump a question back to the top, just edit it to provide more detail. You might even get a good answer?

Comment: well because your answer worked except i have too many classes reliant on the same cell drawing the whole time and would prefer it if the cell drawing were kept in its own class, as an afterthought. Thats why i came back. so do you know of a way to write to an array or not in another view, without delegation? theres got to be an easier way.

Comment: Ok, sorry if I misunderstood. I'll have a crack at an answer then!

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this is by creating a delegate method for the view that has the picker that is fired when the button is pressed that sends the selected information through the delegate method.

Then you make the displaying view's controller implement the delegate method, and set it as the delegate of the second view controller when the second view controller is created.

I wrote a brief [example project](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/585261/DelegationExample.zip) to demonstrate this delegation. It should be easy enough to see how this works and convert it to working with the result of your picker view.

Comment: Thanks for the advice Abizem, i had a look at your example, and i see it works. However i think it overcomplicates the issue, do you know of an easier way? all i need is to call the button press info in another view...?

Answer (score 0):

If the object containing your code above has a reference to the object that contains your array, then one solution would be to make the array a property of its containing object, then in your code above, have something like:

```
[otherViewController.dataArray replaceObjectAtIndex:index withObject:message];
```

This assumes your data array is a NSMutableArray.

It sounds like you're importing the header of your other view controller, but not actually giving it a reference to the object. To complete the circle, add a property to your picker view controller class of type otherViewController (sorry, you haven't given any implementation details so I'm making these up) and when you create / call your picker view controller from your otherViewController, set the value of this property to `self`.

Example pseudocode, for when you do whatever it is to summon up the picker view:

```
 PickerViewController *pvc = [[PickerViewController alloc] init];
pvc.callingView = self;
pvc.index = selectedRowIndex;
// Then present and release your PickerViewController...
```

Comment: i do this and Xcode does not complain about any syntax which is great in a way! However, the array is null when i display it?So somehow its not going across to the other view, and I'm not releasing it anywhere..Any thoughts? :) Trev

Comment: Pardon? Don't put the answer in a new array, you want to get hold of the array from the callingview and add it in to there. You're really going to have to give some details of your two (presumably) view controllers - the table view and the picker view. Otherwise nobody will be able to help you.

Comment: OK so when I'm in the picker view i have the following: